# cisco ePC 3208 router and captive portal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Ok, i have cisco ePC 3208 router, and cable internet goes in router via cable and router is emiting wireless. It can work without computer and it is working fine. Now i want to have capiteve portal with home page for my buisness and user logins.

Is it possible that i use computer as gateway for captive portal, so when user goes to wireless it will redirected to computer local server for authorization and then passed by if user and pass is good, or i need another router or wifi acess point?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible to use the pc as the base for the captive portal.

Give this pc a static IP address, outside the DHCP range of the router and as a gateway choose the IP address of your router. Now setup your Cisco router to act as a router only, giving it, as the IP address of the gateway, that of your pc. In this way all packets will go through your pc, which can act as both firewall and captive portal (the two functions go together).

Comment: And what will emit wireless?

Comment: Your Cisco router, that does not change.

Comment: But i dont understand then, where is setting to act as router only? I thought that i need to turn off radio only?

Comment: @DejanMilosevic The setting must be in your router's GUI

Comment: Ok i added up adress for pc 192.168.9.1 to pc and gateway 192.168.0., from that moment i didnt had internet on my pc, but the wireless worked fine. Next in lan setings i changed ip adress of router to 192.168.9.1 and router restarted, now dhcp starting ip was 192.168.9.10 and neither my pc worked neither wireless worked. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @DejanMilosevic Your gateway is wrong, you wrote 192.168.0, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: 192.168.0.1 i mean

Comment: @DejanMilosevic  If your pc is 192.168.9.1 then the gateway should 192.168.9.xxx, where you can choose anything you want for xxx. Normally, it should be 254, so that your cisco becomes 192.168.9.254.

Comment: And it is like that and dont work. There is no wireless, neither the internet on pc.